# Spring boot app works when I run it, but falls when I test it

Tags: java, spring, tdd

I have a simple spring app with one controller

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

//  @Autowired
//  UserServiceImpl userService;

  @RequestMapping(value="/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getUser(){
//    return userService.greetUser();
    return "Hello user";
  }
```

It works when I start it. If I uncomment `@Autowired` and run with the first return statement using `UserService` it also works.

My Service interface

```
@Service
public interface UserService {
  String greetUser();
  void insertUsers(List<User> users);
}
```

and implementation

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

  @Override
  public String greetUser() {
    return "Hello user";
  }
}
```

But when I test it, the app falls with the following errors

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.UserServiceImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
  public void shouldReturnHelloString() throws Exception{
      this.mockMvc
      .perform(get("/getUser"))
      .andDo(print())
      .andExpect(status().isOk())
      .andExpect(content().string("Hello user"));
  }
}
```

Also, if I remove

```
//  @Autowired
//  UserServiceImpl userService;
```

and run test with second return statement, the test execute without error. I understand that the problem is in the `UserServiceImpl`, but I don't know what it is. What do I need to correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to autowire your bean by an interface, not implementation

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;
```

And also you should remove `@Service` from `UserService` interface

Comment: This did not help. The error remained mostly the same. Only it is now `No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.UserService'`

Comment: Have you added @ComponentScan to your config?

Comment: Adding it to the class that holds the the main method helped. Why didn't it work before?

Comment: if you add this annotation, Spring container can detect and register your beans or components. Without this annotation spring tries to find @Bean methods but I guess your code doesn't contain such methods, so that Spring found nothing and throws an exception

Comment: @Evgenii `@ComponentScan` helps to detect components which annotated with `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository`